# GnuRadio OOT - set_output_multiple

Tags: gnuradio

I have built a convolutional decoder block but for a **default** size of input and output streams.

I am now trying to make it work for **any possible size of input stream**, so I need the size of the output stream to be half the size of the input stream.

According to the [block types](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Types_of_Blocks), I should have used an `Interpolation Block` with the `interpolation` parameter set to 1/2.
However, I have already created a `Basic Block` for that.

Is there another way to define it and make it work for any input, or shall I create an `Interpolation` block? Could I somehow use the `set_output_multiple`?

Thank you!

Comment: By 'basic block;, do you mean general block? You can use a general block, and just change the value of noutput_items to ninput_items/2.

Comment: @MobiZaman the class `gr::basic_block` is the base class for all GNU Radio blocks: hier blocks, top_blocks, what you call "general block", sync blocks, …

Answer (score 0):

> I am now trying to make it work for any possible size of input stream, so I need the size of the output stream to be half the size of the input stream.

So, this is basically a "N items go in, K items go out, N,K∊ℕ" situation.

Specifically, K=N/n, n∊ℕ, so this is an integer *decimator*.

> According to the block types, I should have used an Interpolation Block with the interpolation parameter set to 1/2.

Interpolation is an integer, 1/2 isn't ;) so, nope. this is a decimator, not an interpolator: a decoder outputs *fewer* values than it takes in.